# Asks the user for an input, stores and prints it to the console c#

Tags: c#, beginner

My code is very simple, it asks for an input then stores the input. I am new to c# and wanted to know if it was possible to both ask and accept the input on one line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var input = GetInput();
            Console.WriteLine("Your input:\n{0}", input);

        }
        static string GetInput() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input somthing");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            return input;    

        }
    }
}
```

All feedback welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can, you can use something even smaller such as:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input something");
            Console.WriteLine("Your input: \n{0}", Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine(); //stops the console from closing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can be shorter by removing the extra `using`s

Comment: Since you're only using the `System.Console` class out of the `System` namespace, this could be even shorter with `using static System.Console;` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31852390/3140

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that's totally fine.

Just in case you weren't aware, you might want to add `Console.ReadLine();` to the end of your `Main()` function so that the window stays open until you press enter again. Otherwise the program will print "Your input..." to  the screen, reach the end of the `Main()` function, see that there is nothing else for it to do and exit before you have even had a chance to look at what it printed!

Comment: You could just start your program with Ctrl+F5, which will leave the window open after the application completes.